# NSImageView disappears when the parent NSView wants layer (setWantsLayer:YES)

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nsview, nsimageview

I have a simple custom NSView that has a label and an image. Currently the view works quite well (all the thumbs are instances of my custom view):

[image]

However, I want to set the opacity of these thumbnails. Setting `viewInstance.layer.opacity` doesn't work as the `layer` is `nil`. When I use `[viewInstance setWantsLayer:YES]` first somewhere, and I set the opacity, the opacity of the text changes (it is displayed correctly), but the image view disappears altogether:

[image]

I've tried creating a layer first, assigning it, and then calling `setWantsLayer:` after reading this question: [How to add a CALayer to an NSView on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551992/how-to-add-a-calayer-to-an-nsview-on-mac-os-x) but nothing changed:

```
CALayer *selfLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[selfLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self setLayer:selfLayer];
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
```

I've tried all combinations of creating a layer and displaying it for the image view too (just calling `setWantsLayer:`, creating layer and then assigning it, calling `display` method of it), but still nothing changes:

```
[self addSubview:self.imageView];
CALayer *imageLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[imageLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.imageView setLayer:imageLayer];
[self.imageView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

I've tried adding the image view's layer as a sublayer of the main view and then displaying it:

```
[self.layer addSublayer:self.imageView.layer];
[self.imageView.layer display];
[self.layer display];
```

But still, the images won't display, whereas the text *always* displays correctly. When I comment out the code about assigning and wanting layers, images display again, but obviously, I can't use the layer opacity. I am on OS X Mavericks with OS X SDK 10.8. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I ended up getting rid of `NSImageView` completely and drawing the `NSImage` directly into the layer by setting the layer's `contents` property. However, this is just another approach which solved my problem for this project, it still doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Could you toss your update into an answer so I can upvote it? Workarounds are valid, and it helped me a lot!

Comment: @Sirens sure (sorry for the late reply I was away from computer for 3 weeks), just posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting rid of `NSImageView` completely and drawing the `NSImage` directly into the layer by setting the layer's `contents` property. However, this is just another approach which solved my problem for this project, it still doesn't answer the original question.